# Highcharts How to find legend co-ordinates

Tags: svg, highcharts

I'm using highcharts 3.0. I want to draw a box exactly beside the legend. is there any way to find the legend co-ordinates so that I can use those co-ordinates to draw a rectangle using beside the legend.

Can you please suggest me a method so that I can get the legend co-ordinates

or is there any other way to draw a box beside the legend.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use chart.legend.group.translateX / chart.legend.group.translateY

```
   chart.renderer.text('Series 1', chart.legend.group.translateX,chart.legend.group.translateY)
   .add();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sbochan/K2QqC/

Comment: Sebastian, Thanks this is what I was looking for , This one returns x & y position of legend (i.e top left corner) how can I get top right corner. I mean can I find the width of the legend?

Comment: In the object you can find width, so you neeed only leftCorner + width and you achieve right position.